# Any algorithm to draw lines inside a shape?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, c++

Let's say you have a circle and have all the coordinates (x,y) that make up the circle....
How would you create lines (vertical and horizontal inside it?
[image]

What about a rectangle? What if you have the corner points (x,y) for a rectangle?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure C++ is appropriate? You don't have any existing code to work from. What you have drawn looks like a fishnet created from the extent of your circle points and then intersected (clipped), this would be fairly easy to do in python and only a little more difficult in C++ using OGRGeometry. Unfortunately the C++ API for GDAL/OGR is 404 at the moment so it's a bit hard to give more specific help without some code to work from.

Comment: Do you want to make a grid in QGIS or do you want to understand more about the mathematics behind the geometry involved?

Comment: @MichaelStimson GDAL documentation has been reworked, C++ API is here https://gdal.org/api/ogrlayer_cpp.html

Comment: Generating lines inside a rectangle congruent with the axis is a trivial nested loop. Inside a circle is not significantly harder. But computational geometry is more Math than GIS unless you are using GIS tools, and would still need a coding attempt to be on-topic here in GIS SE.

Comment: Thanks so much @user30184, I will have to bookmark the new location as Google sends me to the old docs which are no more.

Comment: @Spacedman Yeah. I basically need to understand the mathematics that can be used to implement an algorithm that could fill any polygon with lines inside it.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL, when compiled with SpatiaLite, can use all the SpatiaLite functions http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html including ST_SquareGrid

> **ST_SquareGrid**
>   return a grid of square cells (having the edge length of size)
>   precisely covering the input Geometry. The returned Geometry will
>   usually be of the MultiPolygon type (a collection of Squares), but
>   will be a MultiLinestring if the optional edges_only argument is set
>   to TRUE If the optional origin argument (expected to be a Point) is
>   not specified then the (0,0) grid origin will be assumed by default.

Let's take a simple closed ring with 7 vertices for making the WKT shorter

```
LINESTRING ( 760 430, 768.6602540378444 425, 768.6602540378444 415, 760 410, 751.3397459621556 415, 751.3397459621556 425, 760 430 )
```

It looks like this

[image]

The ST_SquareGrid function needs a polygon to cover so we need to polygonize the closed ring with ST_Polygonize first.

Here is a complete ogrinfo command as a proof of consept. Source file "foo.jml" is just a dummy file because ogrinfo cannot be run without data source.

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_SquareGrid(ST_Polygonize(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING ( 760 430, 768.6602540378444 425, 768.6602540378444 415, 760 410, 751.3397459621556 415, 751.3397459621556 425, 760 430)')),10)" foo.jml
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `foo.jml'
      using driver `JML' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (750.000000, 410.000000) - (770.000000, 430.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = ST_SquareGrid(ST_Polygonize(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING ( 760 430, 768.6602540378444 425, 768.6602540378444 415, 760 410, 751.3397459621556 415, 751.3397459621556 425, 760 430)')),10)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  MULTIPOLYGON (((750 410,760 410,760 420,750 420,750 410)),((760 410,770 410,770 420,760 420,760 410)),((750 420,760 420,760 430,750 430,750 420)),((760 420,770 420,770 430,760 430,760 420)))
```

With parameter size=10 the result contains only 4 squares. With size=1 the result has 292 parts and looks like this.

[image]

As a final step you should intersect the cells by the original circle and delete parts which fall outside the circle.